Texture Artifact Problems
The texture on my character is doing strange things.  In earlier shots, it looks fine, but now it's got this rippling effect. I'm wondering if I accidentally changed a setting or something.
Here's a link to the video:
https://we.tl/t-4eK1uNYCkI

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
